# AngularJs 1.4 - No template on page loaded

Tags: angularjs

I use this code for routing:

```
    app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when( "/searchVideo/:videoId", {
        templateUrl : "zoo-search.tpl",
        controller  : "zooSearchCtrl"
        }
    ).
    otherwise({
            templateUrl : "joomla-component.tpl",
            controller  : "joomlaComponentCtrl"
    });
});
```

It works as it supposed to but there's one small issue:
It replaces the existing content in  container by empty template. So the question is: is there a way to load no template at all while a page is being loaded first time? Thanks...

Comment: you want to create a loader gif for the container?

Comment: Make a default page redirect.

Comment: Yes I know it's possible to show a loader image but in this case it loads the page content two times which is not good as for me.

Comment: "Make a default page redirect." - How to do this?